# Methodology for Solving Recursive Functions Problems :

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions, arithmetic, recursion

Given that $f(x) = f(x+3)+ x^2 +x -3$ for all real numbers ,
and $f(1)=2$. Find $f(400)$ .

---

What would be the general approach for these sorts of problems ?

Comment: Did you invent this problem ? I doubt there is a closed-form solution...

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, It was in a Russian Math. Olympiad .

Comment: @YvesDaoust I Checked it again. and corrected $+x^2$ instead of $-x^2$ .

Comment: My bad, it is an easy recurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

From the given equation,

$$f(x+3)=f(x)-(x^2+x-3)$$

and by induction,

$$f(400)=f(1)-\sum_{n=0}^{132}((3n+1)^2+(3n+1)-3)=f(1)-\sum_{n=0}^{132}(9n^2+9n-1).$$

The terms of the summation are easily found using the Faulhaber formulas.

Comment: @yannickneyt: right, thanks for the fix.

Comment: One needs to know $f(x)$ for all $x\in[0,3)$ (or some equivalent set mod $3$) to know the values for all $\mathbb{R}$. Since the question only asked for $f(400)$ given $f(1)$ and $400\equiv1\pmod3$, we're okay.